# php sessions that counts page refereshes dynmically

Tags: php, session

my code is related to breadcrumbs.. that is it should display previous page or from where it is navigated and i achieved it partially , while im refreshing 2-3 times im getting the current page not the previous page.. so pl help me on this

my code lies in session.php as

```
$add = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if($_SESSION['pageadd'][1]!= $_SESSION['pageadd'][2])
{ $_SESSION['pageadd'][2]= $_SESSION['pageadd'][1];
}
echo $_SESSION['pageadd'][2];

if(($_SESSION['pageadd'][1]!= $add) )
{   $_SESSION['pageadd'][1]= $_SESSION['pageadd'][0];
    $_SESSION['pageadd'][0]=$add;

}
```

Comment: Erm, breadcrumbs do not display the last pages a user navigated to, but the logical path down to that specific page.

Comment: You're also assuming indices that may or may not be defined

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your title sounds like you want to include repeated views of the same page but your code and question seems to indicate you don't.

Comment: okay if not i need a functionality such that its displaying previous page hwmuch ever i refresh is dat possible??? @feeela

Comment: hmmm i meant if im refreshing the same page again and again still the breadcrum shud display previous page it had cum from @MrLore

Comment: Of course it is, but your logic be wrong, and dat be true. To your next comment: with what you have that isn't how it should behave at all

Comment: nope i got it if im loading diff pages it will display previous page but if  im refreshin the same page i hv to control such a way that i shud display previous page itself not the current page wic is refreshing...@ElefantPhace

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't a breadcrumb - it's a history for visited pages! This could be achieved with something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['pageadd'])) {
    $_SESSION['pageadd'] = array();
}

// add page
$_SESSION['pageadd'][] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
// only save last 5 pages
if (count($_SESSION['pageadd'])) > 5) {
    array_shift($_SESSION['pageadd']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` it will return you previous url. However you need to store it in some hidden field or session like you are doing now.
Hope this help :)